# How to implement Live camera filter in ARKit with Swift 4?

Tags: ios, camera, swift4, arkit, cifilter

I want to integrate iPhone camera filter in my project, my project is based on ARKit, I want to apply all kind of filter which apple provide in camera app, specially **VIVID,VIVID WARM and VIVID COOL**,

I have tried with all kind of possibilities which i mention below.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        guard let currentBackgroundFrameImage = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage,
        let pixelBufferAddressOfPlane = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(currentBackgroundFrameImage, 1) else { return }

       let x: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(currentBackgroundFrameImage, 1)
       let y: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(currentBackgroundFrameImage, 1)
       memset(pixelBufferAddressOfPlane, 128, Int(x * y) * 2) }
```

I got black and white camera filter using above code.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        let bg = session.currentFrame?.capturedImage
        if (bg != nil) {
            let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: bg!)
            let filter:CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")!
            filter.setDefaults()
            filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            //let filteredImageData = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage

            let context = CIContext()
            //if let result = filter.outputImage,
            if let result = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) ,
                let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result as! CIImage, from: (result as! CIImage).extent) {
                let imageForUser = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                sceneView.scene.background.contents = imageForUser
                sceneView.scene.background.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
            }
        }
}
```

Camera is getting stuck and very slow rending using above code, sometimes app getting crashed due to memory issue. (tested in iPhone XR)

Please help me for live camera filter functionality. It would be great if you provide me any code for ARKit camera filter. Thank you.

Comment: For starters, don't create a new `CIContext` every frame. This is a really expensive object. Try creating it during init and re-use it every frame.